# Can't import/include external doxygen configuration file properly

Tags: documentation, doxygen, doxywizard

I have a simple doxygen project consisting of `Doxyfile` and a configuration file, `project.txt`. In the `project.txt` file, I have some manually written documentation that uses cross-references to auto generated documentation from my code, and it all works fine.

I am trying to break down my project into subsections, like:

```
project.txt
disclaimer.txt
readme.txt
```

So, I've put Doxygen markup code into `disclaimer.txt` and `readme.txt`, and I updated the `EXAMPLE_PATH` in my `Doxyfile` to be:

```
EXAMPLE_PATH=./
```

Finally, in `project.txt`, I just added the lines:

```
\include disclaimer.txt
\include readme.txt
```

I expected `disclaimer.txt` and `readme.txt` to be imported into `project.txt` so they are treated as Doyxgen markup, but instead, they are interpreted as text, and are rendered as-is in a code block, as if wrapped by `\code` and `\endcode` tags, making the include operation useless.

Is there some way to include additional Doxygen configuration files and actually have them parsed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can include Doxygen config files at arbitrary points in your code like that. I know you could add it to you file list though, etc:

```
INPUT   = ../PATH_TO_SOURCE_CODE_HEADER_1.h  \
          ./project.txt                      \
          ./disclaimer.txt                   \
          ./readme.txt
```

Also, make sure each of your `.txt` files is wrapped with `/**` and `*/` if you're using C, for example.

Comment: Worth noting that doxygen supports markdown since 1.8.2 - so instead of .txt with odd C-style-delimited comments, you can have vanilla text with easy-readable _emphasis_ **bold** etc. in a `.md` or `.markdown` text file.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude):

> \include  This command can be used to include a source file as a block of code.

Which seems to agree with the behaviour you see.

I am not sure if you can include pages into others as you want.

The best solution I can see is to use `\subpage` instead, which will both create a link to the other pages and make them subpages of the main page (this will show in the html related pages section as a dropdown hierarchy).

Usage inside `project.txt` would be:

```
\subpage disclaimer
\subpage readme
```

Supposing that `disclaimer.txt` contains a line like `\page disclaimer Disclaimer`

Also make sure that `*.txt` is in your `FILE_PATTERNS`.